# Return string value of reader.result on FileReader

Tags: javascript, image, function, vue.js, base64

I've been triying to return a string in a reader.onloadend but it keeps me returning my entire function.

my function below:

```
uploadFile() {
      let vm = this;
      var file = vm.$refs["testeLogo"].files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log(reader.result); // returns me a string base64
        document.querySelector("#supe").setAttribute("src", this.imagem);
        return reader.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

How can I return the value of the string in a proper way, because it keeps returning my own function instead of the reader.result that is printed on the console.log

Comment: It is asynchronous, you can not return from it. Use async await....

Comment: Don't use filereader + base64 to preview images when you can just use `URL.createObjectURL(file)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are working on a Vue app (let me know if don't):

Just use the `imageBase64` variable wherever you want in your template, it will be updated once the file is loaded.

```js
data () {
  return {
    imageBase64: ''
  }
},

methods: {
  uploadFile() {
    let vm = this;
    var file = vm.$refs["testeLogo"].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      document.querySelector("#supe").setAttribute("src", this.imagem);
      
      vm.imageBase64 = reader.result
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Also remember to not query the DOM directly using Vue, you can directly bind `imagem` variable to the `img` `src` attribute:

```js
<img :src="imagem" alt="" />
```